# Android unit testing issues with dagger2 and kotlin

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, dagger-2

I am trying to create a  dagger component interface in the test folder of android,but after Dagger is done with the generated class its show an error as "Cannot access TestComponent which is a supertype of com.example.animals.di.DaggerTestAppComponent.Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependency".Can you please help me to fix this issue.

```
gradle dependecies:
def lifeCycleExtensionVersion = '1.1.1'
def supportVersion = '28.0.0'
def retrofitVersion = '2.3.0'
def glideVersion = '4.9.0'
def rxJavaVersion = '2.1.1'
def navVersion = '2.1.0-alpha05'
def daggerVersion = '2.14.1'
def mockitoVersion = '2.11.0'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportVersion"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifeCycleExtensionVersion"

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navVersion"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navVersion"

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofitVersion"

    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxJavaVersion"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxJavaVersion"

    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glideVersion"

    implementation "com.android.support:palette-v7:$supportVersion"


    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVersion"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion"


    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:$mockitoVersion"
    testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1"
    kaptTest "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
 }

TestAppComponent:
   package com.example.animals.di

 import com.example.animals.base.BaseTest
 import dagger.Component
 import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
@Component(modules = [])
interface TestAppComponent {
   fun inject(baseTest: BaseTest)
}
```

BaseTest:
        package com.example.animals.base

```
 import android.app.Application
 import com.example.animals.di.DaggerTestAppComponent
 import org.junit.Before
 import org.mockito.Mockito

open class BaseTest {

    val application = Mockito.mock(Application::class.java)

    @Before
     fun setUp() {
     configureDi()

    }

    private fun configureDi() {
       var testAppComponent = DaggerTestAppComponent.builder().build()

        testAppComponent.inject(this)
    }
 }
```

Comment: I have the same issue but the interesting thing is that it still compiles and it still works even though it complains ‍♂️

Comment: Yeah,exactly.Anyways i have found a different way of using the daggerappcomponent class now.Instead of creating a brand new in testing i have started using the one created already during the development and it is working perfectly fine now and the later one i feel is a better way of using the dagger class.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem here setting up my tests on [our repo here](https://github.com/toggl/android/pull/196).
When seeing examples from [Tivi](https://github.com/chrisbanes/tivi/blob/master/gradle/config-kotlin-sources.gradle), I noticed that our generated sources weren't being included to the source sets.

Adding a gradle script somewhere in your project should fix your problem.

Ex: https://github.com/toggl/android/blob/768f01b55c47ffd3bb7c4a82dea4abf50eac9e1c/database-android/build.gradle#L46-L63 (same as Tivi).

```
main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
debug.java.srcDirs += 'src/debug/kotlin'
release.java.srcDirs += 'src/release/kotlin'
test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'

// For kapt stubs
main.java.srcDirs += [file("$buildDir/generated/source/kapt/main")]
debug.java.srcDirs += [file("$buildDir/generated/source/kapt/debug")]
release.java.srcDirs += [file("$buildDir/generated/source/kapt/release")]
test.java.srcDirs += [file("$buildDir/generated/source/kapt/test")]

// For kotlin code gen during kapt
main.java.srcDirs += [file("$buildDir/generated/source/kaptKotlin/main")]
debug.java.srcDirs += [file("$buildDir/generated/source/kaptKotlin/debug")]
release.java.srcDirs += [file("$buildDir/generated/source/kaptKotlin/release")]
test.java.srcDirs += [file("$buildDir/generated/source/kaptKotlin/test")]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot David.