# Android Dagger2 JUnit generated TestComponent class not recognizing/recognized in TestClass

Tags: android, junit4, dagger-2

Bit of intro here

- Project has `core` and `app` components
- Some utility classes are placed in `core` component to ease the JUnit tests in other modules
- Dagger is used across all the modules

Here is the project structure

```
core
 ___src
 ______main
 _________com.core
 ____________CoreComponent
 ______test
 _________com.core.test
 ____________SomeMockData

 ___build/generated/source/kapt
 ______coreDebug
 _________com.core
 ____________DaggerCoreComponent

app
 ___src
 ______main
 _________com.foo
 ____________AwesomeComponent
 ____________ConcreteClassA
 ______test
 _________com.foo
 ____________TestAweseomeComponent
 ____________MyJUnitTest

 ___build/generated/source/kapt
 ______appDebug
 _________com.foo
 ____________DaggerAwesomeComponent
 ______appDebugUnitTest
 _________com.foo
 ____________DaggerTestAwesomeComponent
```

In app `build.gradle`, core added as both main and test depencency

```
implementation project(':core')
testImplementation project(':core')
```

Dagger 2 - added for codegen, and it successfully generates DaggerTestComponent

```
testImplementation dagger.xx  
kaptTest daggerProcessor.xx
```

There are two issues in here

1. `SomeMockData` placed inside `core/test`  is not accessible in `app/test` sources (IDE doesn't show any error though). While running `MyJUnitTest` it throws the error.
2. Generated `DaggerTestAwesomeComponent` not detecting `TestAwesomeComponent` and `DaggerTestAwesomeComponent` is not visible in `MyJUnitTest`. As we know the generated `DaggerAwesomeComponent` works simply fine.

> NOTE: For simplicity I left out the injector classes, `MyJUnitTest_MembersInjector` is generated as well. As I have @Inject in the test class

Comment: I have the same problem. Tried Invalidate Caches/Restart, cleaning generated code and running assembleAndroidTest, assembleDebugUnitTest.
Also ImmutableMap and CanIgnoreReturnValue classes cannot be resolved in 'test' section. In code section everything works fine.

kaptTest dependencies are provided.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60985281/android-unit-testing-issues-with-dagger2-and-kotlin
thread noticed that tests still work. In my case test works even with errors too.