# Dagger2 issue in Android Studio

Tags: android, junit, dagger-2

I'm writing some JUnits for my Android app which use Dagger2. To demonstrate my problem I simplified my test. 
In gradle I have those dependencies related to Junits and dagger:

```
    //dependency injection
api "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
api "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$dagger_version"
api "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$dagger_version"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger_version"

//unit testing
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
//dagger testing
testImplementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
testAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
```

Here is my Test class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Test extends TestCase {

  @Inject
  String greating;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    TestComponent component = DaggerTestComponent.builder().testModule(new TestModule()).build();
    component.inject(this);
  }

  @org.junit.Test
  public void test() {
      assertEquals("Hello!", greating);
  }
}
```

Component for DI

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {TestModule.class})
public interface TestComponent {
  void inject(Test test);
}
```

Test module for DI

```
@Module
public class TestModule {
  @Singleton
  @Provides
  public String providesHello() {
    return "Hello!";
  }
}
```

My problem is that during the execution of the test, DaggerTestComponent is generated, but Android Studio underlines with red color the `new TestModule()` on line where is `TestComponent component = DaggerTestComponent.builder().testModule(new TestModule()).build();` On hower it shows me *testModule(TestModule) in builder cannot be aplied to mytestpackage.TestModule.* If I open generated DaggerTestComponent it look ok but contains error cannot resolve symbol TestModule on it's every occurence.

DaggerTestComponent is generated under

```
\app\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\debugUnitTest\out\mytestpackage
```

My test and related classes are located in

```
\app\src\test\java\mytestpackage
```

Regardless this, the Test works fine and ends as **passed**.

How do I get rid off this annoying error? Do I need to configure additional classpaths in gradle or set something else in AndroidStudio? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Finally problem solved by adding

```
android.sourceSets {
  test.java.srcDirs += 
  [file("$buildDir/generated/ap_generated_sources/debugUnitTest/out")]
}
```

Thanks to *Daivid* for solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61329262/4345570